# offsetTop is not working

Tags: jquery

i am using scrollTo. but offsetTop is not working. I want go to that position with top 300px

```
$('#tab1').on('click', function(){
        $('body').scrollTo('#services38',{duration:'slow', offsetTop : '300'});
        //$('body').scrollTo(400);
    });
```

Comment: how about using just $('body').scrollTop(300) ???

Comment: Yes its working but smooth effect doesn't work

Comment: Then you can use animate method... would I answer on this??

Comment: I have use  $("#tab1").on('click', function(){
  $("body").animate({ scrollTop: '420' });
 });   but its not working in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#tab1').on('click', function(){
$('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: '300'
    }, 1000, 'linear');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

offsetTop is read-only, while scrollTop is read/write. So you need to use second one here.

To make it animated effect try:

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#services38").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Comment: That section comes to page top. It is not consider scrollTop